# How to filter a value from an input in Angular 13

Tags: angular

Need to filter JSON Data when the user type the input in the HTML, the data is retrieved from a backend server, in this case i managed to filter the data when the all the JSON has been brought but i need to do a query when the users write and click the submit button.

This is as far i have reached:

I create a service to bring the data

```
//services.ts
this.informesNodes = SOME_EXAMPLE_JSON_URL
getNodes(): Observable<InformesCounter> {
    return this.http.get<InformesCounter>(`${this.informesNodes}`);
  }
```

Then i filter the data with find/filter

```
//component.ts
showNodes() {
this.frontService.getNodes()
  .subscribe((data: Claves) => {
    const { data: nodeCollection } = data;
    console.log(nodeCollection);
    nodeCollection.forEach((item: any) => {
      item.attributes.titulo.forEach((item: any) => {
          const myTitle = nodeCollection.find((element: any) => element.attributes.titulo)
          console.log(myTitle);
          this.nodeTitle = myTitle;           
      })
    })
    console.log(this.nodeTitle);
  });
```

}

And in my HTML

```
<form #form="ngForm">
                      <div class="form--inline clearfix d-flex">
                         <div class="form-item">
                            <label for="edit-combine">Buscador de Informes</label>
                            <div class="inner-addon left-addon" style="position: relative">
                               <input style="margin-top: 8px; width: 100%;" placeholder="Buscar" type="text" id="edit-combine" name="combine" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="caja_texto form-text form-control lupa" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (click)="showNodes()">
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div *ngFor="let info of nodeTitle | front: searchText">
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </form>
```

My JSON have a collection of objects with the following attributes:

```
   {
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "bdfb9f2d-d25d-44c1-b1e7-54ef0142e540",
            "links": {
                "describedby": {
                    "href": "http://localhost/webagn2019/jsonapi/node/informes/resource/schema"
                },
                "self": {
                    "href": "myurl"
                }
            },
            "attributes": {
                "drupal_internal__nid": 12,
                "drupal_internal__vid": 26,
                "langcode": "es",
                "revision_timestamp": "2019-07-01T14:01:36+00:00",
                "revision_log": null,
                "status": true,
                "titulo": "EL TITULO",    
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

The idea is to bring the json response when filtering the result so i don't have to bring all the data at once. thank you.

Comment: A bit unclear what you’re asking here, sorry. What is not working with what you have now exactly?

Comment: I need to filter before getting the data. If i bring the entire json of 3000 objects it will take an eternity.

Comment: I guess you’ll need to do that serverside.. right..?

Comment: Check if the endpoint that you are using have pagination implemented. If that is not the case, like @MikeOne pointed out this is up to backend.

Comment: Yes i can use the pagination. But i dont know how i can manage it from the front end. Could you give me an example??? Thanks!!!